# Ext JS - Multiline display field

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I display a multi-line `textarea` in a `displayfield` but the text is shown as concatenated instead of line by line.

Here is the sample fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/10f6

How can I make the text to be displayed in `displayfield` in exactly same way with `textarea`?

Comment: Like this: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/10f8

Comment: exactly, if you change your comment to a post then I can check it as right answer. @CD..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `renderer`, like:

```
renderer: function(value){
  return value.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
}
```

For example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/10f8

Comment: *FYI* you could just use: `renderer: Ext.util.Format.nl2br` - [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/10no) :)